# Ionic back button translation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, internationalization, back-button, angular-translate

I can customize the back button text in my Ionic project like this:

```
.config(
    function ($ionicConfigProvider) {
        $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.text("Back");
    }
})
```

Now I'm trying to translate it. I use angular-translate in my project:

```
$ionicConfigProvider.backButton.text($filter('translate')('BACK'));
```

But the translate filter seems to be unavailable during config phase. Is there any way of overcoming this issue or any better way of translating the back-button text?

Update: please note this is not about how to use the translate filter during config phase, but how to translate the back button properly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the text of the back button threw the HTML:

```
<ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
  <i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> 
   Back
</ion-nav-back-button>
```

To use Angular-translate:

```
<ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
  <i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> 
  {{'BACK' | translate}}
</ion-nav-back-button>
```

Comment: This one seems the best choice since translating during config phase is not a really good practice.